# What is the correct word for charges we pay at Gym?

Tags: word-choice

As the question states, what should be the correct word for the money we pay at the Gym.

What I think:

It can't be **fees**, as we paid that  at school/colleges.

It can't be **payment**, as we are not purchasing something.

It can't be **rent**, as we don't partially own the thing.

So, what would be the correct thing?

Comment: Why would it matter that you paid fees in school/college? That doesn't preclude you from paying other fees; in fact, unless you're a hermit living in a mountain cave, you do without a doubt pay lots of fees in your everyday life.

Comment: ... Quite. It's like saying 'This can't be mash because we had that last year.'

Comment: And if you're playing a specific sport at the gym, like squash, you certainly can rent a court.

Answer (score 3):

In Britain they might well be called ***subs*** - short for ***subscriptions***. That is the word which usually applies in the case of small clubs and associations to cover admin costs.

If it is a larger commercial gym, they are probably called ***fees***.

Answer (score 1):

You can call these entrance fees or membership fees, depending on the exact situation.

Comment: Suppose, [here]where I'm living, I want to tell the Gym owner that I'll pay his charges after 1 week.  So should I say him, that I'll pay your fees 1 week later?

Comment: @neil Yes, you can use fees in this case, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

There are many terms that describe the monetary amount that is paid in return for membership to a club, group or event, and most have been described in other answers.

One that is missing is ['dues'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/due?q=dues#due__9)

> **noun**
>
> 2 An obligatory payment; a fee:
>    ‘he had paid trade union dues for years’
>
> *www.oxforddictionaries.com*

All of these correctly describe the amount of money in your example in general terms.

However in the UK the specific term that is often used when referring to this amount of money allowing access to a gym is, simply, 'gym membership'

e.g. "I am using this to pay my gym membership", or "How much is your gym membership?"